# why customtkinter elements have a strange shape

Tags: button, element, shapes, customtkinter, pointer-aliasing

I'm trying to use customtkinter. i downloaded the examples and when i try theme, all the elements have a strange shape [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlMaC.png) which don't look like the screens of the examples on github.
I searched on google but didn't find a way to solve this.
I use

- Ubuntu 22.04
- Anaconda
- tested on Python 3.8 and python 3.10
- the customtkinter (V5.0.3) was installed using pip

I tried two different versions of python, tried reinstalling the lib
was expecting elements with this kind of shape https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/blob/master/documentation_images/image_example_dark_Windows.png

Answer (score 1):

Well apparently it's a known bug with anaconda and there is no proper solution yet. You can find the bug report here https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6833

An ugly workaround wich actual works is to replace your conda env libtk8.6 by a symlink to system libtk8.6:

```
cd [Your_conda_env_path]/lib/
mv libtk8.6.so libtk8.6.so.old
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtk8.6.so .
```

Comment: It worked for me, thanks!